# Check existence of dynamic field: Element [x] is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to check if the value of a dynamic form field is empty or not, but am getting errors at every point. What I am trying to do is: if the form value is empty, do nothing and skip it. If it is not empty, just go on and fill other details.

Here is the code I have:

```
<cfset filename = "form.oldFile_" & #k# & "_" & #ii#>
<cfset fname = isDefined(form["form.oldFile_#k#_#ii#"])>
<cfdump var="#fname#" abort>
```

I am getting this error while running the above code:

> Element form.oldFile_1_1 is undefined in a Java object of type class
>   coldfusion.filter.FormScope.

I have also tried `evaluate`, but get similar errors.

```
<cfset fname = isDefined('form["form.oldFile_#k#_#ii#"]')>
```

Comment: is the form name `form.oldFile_1_1`? or is it just `oldFile_1_1`?

Comment: i corrected it and tested it again, i removed the extra `form` and still the same error

Comment: So ... what is the actual name of the field? :-) As Matt mentioned, your code probably seems to have many "form." prefixes. i.e. It is `form["someFieldName"]`, not `form["FORM.someFieldName"]`

Comment: the actual name is: `oldFile_1_1` - nowthe `_1_1` is incremental as there are many fields

Comment: (Edit) Well like Matt mentioned, your code has too many "form." prefixes. i.e. The syntax is `form["someFieldName"]` - not `form["FORM.someFieldName"]`. Also, IsDefined() does not allow square brackets. Instead use `structKeyExists(FORM, "someFieldName"& dynamicPart)`

Comment: Did `<cfdump var="#form#">` reveal anything useful?

Answer (score 2):

try using structKeyExists

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "oldFile_#k#_#ii#")>
    <cfset fname = form["oldFile_#k#_#ii#"]>
</cfif>
```

or

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "oldFile_#k#_#ii#")>
    <cfset fname = form["oldFile_" & k & "_" & ii]>
</cfif>
```